# Simple way to show the ideal $\langle 1+x \rangle$ in $V^5[x]$ corresponds to the code in $V^5$ with all words of even weight?

Tags: abstract-algebra, coding-theory

$V^5$ is the set of length $5$ codewords. $V^5[x] = \mathbb F_2[x]/ \langle x^5-1\rangle $.

Show that the ideal $\langle 1+x \rangle$ in $V^5[x]$ corresponds to the code in $V^5$ with all words of even weight.

Of course, one way of doing this is generating an ideal with $ 1+x $, but this is obviously quite time consuming. I believe the homework problem has a more efficient solution...but I can't think of anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Pray tell us what is $V^5[x]$? I might guess that it means $\Bbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^5-1\rangle$, but others may not be as psychic, and I may be wrong. You should not assume here that the notation of the textbook your teacher uses is in universal use. Some convergence is happening, but people's tastes will always vary.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought this was conventional notation. Yes it is what you said.

Comment: Hint: if $c(x)$ is divisible by $x+1$, then it belongs to the ideal generated by $x+1$ and enjoys the property that $c(1) = 0$. What does this tell you about the _parity_ of the Hamming weight of the codeword $c(x)$? Do you _really_ need to _generate_ all members of the ideal _explicitly_ to prove what you are asked to prove?

Comment: Here's what I tried.

In order to construct the ideal $\langle 1+x \rangle$ take some $a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+ex^4 \in V^5[x]$, multiply it by $1+x \mod x^5-1$. 

You obtain some $(a+e)+(b+a)x+(c+b)x^2+(d+c)x^3 +(e+d)x^4$ in the ideal. To get the weight just sum the coefficients:

$(a+e) + (b+a) + (c+b) + (d+c) + (e+d)=2(a+b+c+d+e)$, which is even.

Comment: If $c(x) = \sum_{i=0}^6 c_ix^i$, then $c(1) = \sum_{i=0}^6 c_i$. What if $c(x)$ is divisible by $x+1$ as all polynomials in the ideal are? Now, $c(x) = (x+1)b(x)$ but what is the value of $c(1)$ and why on earth does the value of $c(1)$ not depend on the value of $b(1)$, that is, the coefficients of $b(x)$, at all?

Comment: @DilipSarwate sorry, I did not see this. Since $c(1)=0$, it tells us that when there is an even amount of powers of $x$ in the polynomial when it is expanded. This tells us that there is an even number of coefficients, hence an even weight. Basically telling us that any generator that is divisible by $(x+1)$ will make an ideal with vectors of even weight.

Comment: Have you given any thought to the possibility that **every** polynomial in the ideal $\langle x+1\rangle$ just might happen to be a multiple of $x+1$? And if so, then every polynomial in the ideal will have an even number of nonzero coefficients and hence even Hamming weight?  But if not, I suggest that you simply brute-force **generate** all the elements of the ideal (there can be at most $2^5 = 32$ elements since it is a subspace of $V^5$) and verify that each and every one of the elements of the ideal has even weight.

Comment: I have :). Thanks.